# Flip labels 180° with CartoCSS

Tags: carto, mapbox, cartocss

How can I flip labels on my lines upside down? I am styling some OSM data and the cartocss is currently

```
#streets{ 
text-size: 14; 
text-name: [NAME]; 
text-face-name: 'ATRotSemSanLigIta Regular'; 
text-fill: #000; 
text-halo-fill: fadeout(white, 40%); 
text-halo-radius: 2; 
text-placement: line; 
text-dy: 12; 
}
```

I think its via text-orientation but cannot get it to fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
text-orientation:[angle];
```

where  `angle` is a number with values from 0 to 360.

Comment: this is close but I want the labels on lines. When text-placement:line is selected, the text-orientation is overridden

Comment: I think you are right, although the documentation does not say anything about it.

Comment: yep, messed around a bunch and can't get them both simultaneously